# How to access a pandas Dataframe when running an oracle query in Python?

Tags: python, oracle, pandas

I currently have a Pandas dataframe and am trying to see if I can reference it when querying an Oracle table in Python. Ideally, I would like to reference the pandas dataframe in the `join` statement of an oracle query.

In Python, I'm able to pass a string into oracle where statement, like this:

```
select *
from a
where 
var in (""" + df + """)
```

But reach an oracle limit on the number of things 1000 elements that can be passed in through my where statement.

Ideally, I would like to use `join` on the dataframe directly in order to avoid the Oracle limit. Eventually, I'd like to store this new data into a separate dataframe.

```
select *
from df pd
left join a oracle
on pd.var = oracle.var
```

Is there any other way to access existing pandas when trying to run an oracle query in pandas?